# Number of OpenMP threads limited to 4 on Ubuntu 14.04, gfortran 4.8.2

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, openmp, scheduler, gfortran

Ubuntu 14.04, gfortran 4.8.2, running on a HP Proliant DL580 G5 with four Xeon X7350's installed.  16 hardware threads available.

OpenMP environment variables:
OMP_NUM_THREADS=16

Compiled each .f, .f90 file with the following flags:
-O2 -I/usr/include -fdefault-real-8 -fopenmp
Linked with:
-O2 -fdefault-real-8 -fopenmp -fmax-stack-var-size=1000000
(the stack size flag was in place due to earlier problems with PRIVATE vars and ALLOCATE, but those are solved...)

When running, I can't get more than four hardware threads to be utilized!

Is there something about the Linux scheduler that I don't know?  <-- rhetorical, obviously...

OpenMP directives aren't doing anything funky -- simple PARALLELs, marking some variables SHARED.  No nested PARALLELs.  I had a DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1) directive before my loops, but removing it has no effect.

I know that the OMP_NUM_THREADS is being obeyed, because when I set it to 1, 2, or 3, and watch the output from top, the corresponding number of cores are used.  Anything over 4 is ignored.  It seems like there's a maximum that's set in some configuration somewhere.  I've tried various games with GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY, OMP_PLACE, etc., and nothing helps.

I've even tried hardwiring things with NUM_THREADS() clauses, omp_lib omp_set_num_threads() calls, etc., and again nothing helps.

The same code compiled with Intel Fortran XE running on a Windows 7 x64 box with four hardware threads fills up all four threads nicely, with no env variables set anywhere, and with no omp_lib calls made.

Any ideas?

Edit:  I'm seeing this same behavior on an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop with 12 usable cores.  Running the same program shows that up to 4 cores are being used, no more, so it probably isn't anything specific to the HP Proliant.

Comment: Check that your session not confined within a cpuset, e.g. by something like `cat /proc/self/status` and looking at the value of `Cpus_allowed_list`, alternatively at the value of `Cpus_allowed`. Mind that the latter one is a bitmask. The affinity mask as set by e.g. `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` is bitwise **AND**-ed with the one in `Cpus_allowed`.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to the existence of things like cpusets -- yet another thing to learn about -- but it doesn't look like any apply.  Cpus_allowed is 0xffffffff, and Cpus_allowed_list is 0-31...

Comment: OK, this is crazy -- I couldn't wait anymore, so I just tried running the thing on our full problem, *and I get all 16 threads!*  The original trial run was using a config file that asked for an array (SHARED) that was about 73Mb.  The full problem allocates about 20Gb to the same array, and lo and behold, I get everything I ask for.  Is the OpenMP runtime so smart that it knows that overhead for thread creation wouldn't be worth spending time for the 73Mb case, but would be for the 20Gb case?

Comment: The standard allows for quite some thoughtfulness to be present on the side of the OpenMP runtime, but the GCC runtime is not known for being one of those intelligent OpenMP runtimes. It is probably something else (and probably trivial) that causes such behaviour.

Comment: It is probably trivial, and perhaps it's something in my code (implying a workaround can probably be found) -- or maybe it's the phase of the moon.  Who knows!  I'll investigate further with different runs...